# Delphi 7 : how to generate class hierarchy?

Tags: delphi, class-hierarchy

I am seeking to understand someone else's code in Delphi 7 (I suspect that newer version have this built in, but I don't want to spring > $1k for the newest version).

Are their any (preferably FOSS) tools which will help me generate a class hierarchy diagram?

---

Actually, the class browser in [GExperts](http://www.gexperts.org) is ok. Maybe not as good as the accepted answer, but just one of a great collection of tools

Comment: +1 for the class browser in GExperts

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [ESS-model from SourceForge](http://essmodel.sourceforge.net/).
If you Load and .PAS (also .DPR, .CLASS,...) with some classes this program generate a Class Diagram and some Documentation. It's free and you can access to code source. 
[image]

Regards

Comment: +1 very cool! As a bonus, I was able to integrate into Delphi's Tools menu. Just set the "program" to the path-to-your\EssModel.exe
and set the parameter:  $EDNAME
Works like a charm!

Comment: Inside ESSModel (v. 2.2), on File/ChangeSettings menu, the program has the options "ShortCut on contextmenu for sourcefiles" and "Shortcut on Tools Menu in Delphi IDE" that can made this changes for you.  ;-)

Comment: Perhaps useful for small applications, I found its generated (single) class diagram for a large application (.dpr or open folder) to be simply unusable. I like the ability to drill into packages or classes and, the generated documentation. ESS-Model has its niche but not for large applications - IMHO.

Comment: It's does not support generics.

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK ModelMaker 6.2 was included with Delphi 7, it's a UML tool. You can import your source code in it and generate class diagrams etc, I really don't remember anymore all of it's features, but I do remember that ModelMaker is awesome tool and it's sure worth a look.

Update: Model Maker (now MMX) is now free for all supported Delphi IDEs

Comment: +1 ModelMaker rocks! If it wasn't included, get it... It'l save you a lot of headaches.

Comment: I am evaluating ModelMaker and while it seems powerful, the learning curve seems steep - or the product is just unintuitive to me, a former Rose and Enterprise Architect (EA) user. I suspect an investment of time would pay off. Again, seems very powerful. If I owned it already I'd stick with it. Unlikely to shell out ~$300 USD for it though as I have an immediate and temporary need.

Comment: Updated: Model Maker (now MMX) is now free for all supported Delphi IDEs

Answer (score 3):

You can take a look at our [SynProject tool](http://synopse.info/forum/viewforum.php?id=16).

Synopse SynProject is an open source application for code source versioning and automated documentation of Delphi projects.

There is a pascal source parser, which will create all classes hierarchy documentation.

And it's much more than a parser: you can write the whole Specifications/Architecture/Design/Test/Release documents list in an integrated manner.

There are some tutorials, screenshots and resulting documentation sample in the above link.

Answer (score 2):

Peganza's [Pascal Analyzer](http://www.peganza.com/) (not FOSS)

Comment: +1 Thanks for posting. Now I need to decide if that is worth $159 to me (a sizeable chunk of the $1k for the latest version of Delphi; I must check if that has the functionality I seek).    Meantime, I will continue to search

Answer (score 1):

[Doc-o-matic](http://www.doc-o-matic.com)'s documentation generator creates class hierarchies. They have a free express version you can try.